# Is < binary relation a strict partial order on IEEE doubles?

Tags: floating-point, partial-order

To me it looks that it is:

- irreflexivity: NaN < NaN == false
- transitivity: if a < b and b < c then a < c (the antecedent is never true for NaNs)
- asymmetry: if a < b then not b < a (again, the antecedent is never true for NaNs)

However, it cannot be extended to non-strict partial ordering <= because there's no (reflexive) equality for doubles (NaN != NaN).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. (Though you need to consider signed zero as well as NaNs.) For extra confirmation:

> > [So, the floating-point operator< does not form weak order and therefore does not form a total order. It is, however, a partial order.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4367.html#Floating)
>
> However, it cannot be extended to non-strict partial ordering <= because there's no (reflexive) equality for doubles (NaN != NaN).

It *can* be extended, but `<=` as defined by IEEE isn't that extension.